# How to add visual indicator of focus for Radio Button for Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I know that this is an [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=913103) in Firefox that radio button is not highlighted as expected when focused. How should we get around this issue? I read another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896967/javascript-radio-button-focus-doesnt-work-on-firefox) taking about this issue, there is no perfect solution though. So I try to ask again to see if there is any better solution.

I have tried to add the css for focused radio button

```
outline: 1px dotted;
```

But this is not good enough in the sense that Chrome is not using dotted line for highlight.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the same method that many developers of Accessible sites use. Because the faint outlines (dotted or otherwise) that most browsers provide as default simply cannot be seen by keyboard users (especially those with poor eyesight), because those outlines are much too faint, many developers working to W3C standards solve it by giving an outline of 2 or 3 px, solid and in a good-contrasting colour. They do this for *all* fields and links, not just radio buttons:

```
.... { outline: 3px solid orange }
```

(choose a colour that stands out well on your pages). This enables keyboard users to see where the focus has gone when links etc are dotted around the page. (Ever tried tabbing through a page with the tab key and tried to see where the faint browser outline has gone to this time?)

Doing this for all links and fields would  both solve your problem and make a start with Accessibility for handicapped people!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to remove the radio button image (css hack) and then use a css sprite to define one image on radio unselected, another on radio selected, and then use the standard css hover to define your hover style.